# Mixing more arrays together in a loop

Tags: php

I created 3  textarea, where inside i can add words separated by commas , which will output 3 arrays.

I have 3 separate arrays :

```
array('fruit','veg');
array('color','other');
array('white','black','red','orange');
```

So now i need to make a single loop, that combine the for first word of array 1 ( ex fruit) with words of other 2 arrays.

Ex output :
fruit color white
fruit color black
fruit color red
fruit color orange
fruit other white
......
veg other black
....
etc

I need to mix all word in the 3 arrays, for a total of 16 phrases ( in these case ).
I tryed with this code but the output not working as expect

```
<?php
    $array1 = array('red','orange', 'blu', 'green');
    $array2 = array('fruit', 'veg');
    $array3 = array('color', 'other');
?>

<ul>
    <?php 
        foreach($array3 as $key => $src) {
            foreach($array2 as $typeKey => $typeArr) {
                foreach($array1 as $index => $val){ 
                    echo '<li>'. $dest[$key][$index][$typeKey] = $val .'</li>';
                }   
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to get as output? One-dimension array? Just output those using `echo`? (just print `echo "$val $typeArr $src";`) What is `$dest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$array1 = ['fruit', 'veg'];
$array2 = ['color', 'other'];
$array3 = ['white', 'black', 'red', 'orange'];
?>

<ul>
    <?php 

 foreach($array1 as $v1){
     $str = '<li>';
     foreach($array2 as $v2){
         foreach($array3 as $v3){
             $str .= $v1. ' '.$v2.' '.$v3.' ';
         }
     }
     echo $str.'</li>';
 }
    ?>
</ul>
```